# Setting dotnetcli no_proxy

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, nuget, azure-pipelines

I'm pulling my hair out. I've got an On Prem installation of Azure DevOps, and a pair of build agents. We're trying to move to .net core, but we have never been able to get it to work to push the nuget packages into DevOps feed. This should be straight forward.

The whole environment is hidden behind corporate firewall and proxy, and while the proxy config is good for nuget pull, and any other activity you care to name, we cannot invoke nuget push (or dotnet push) to our internal package repository. The only error I get is a 502 (bad gateway) from tunnel.js, but I've explicitly set the address of the DevOps server in NO_PROXY (environment variables, .proxy & .proxybypass for the devops agent, netsh winhttp proxy, build agent user internet connection settings, and %AppData%\Nuget\Nuget.Config file). Git works, nuget restore works, build works, packaging works, but the dotnet push (or nuget push) fail with this error.

Can anyone suggest any other places I might need to set a proxy bypass or no_proxy setting?

Answer (score 0):

There can be many reasons why you are getting this problem, which may be related to your organization network, users roles and permissions or even task may be restricted by any policy.

But if above mentioned things are not true in your case then you should **configure NuGet tools to authenticate with Azure Artifacts and other NuGet repositories**. If all of the Azure Artifacts feeds you use are in the same organization as your pipeline, you can use the **NuGetAuthenticate task** without specifying any inputs. Check this [Restore and push NuGet packages within your organization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/nuget-authenticate?view=azure-devops#restore-and-push-nuget-packages-within-your-organization) document for more information.

> This task must run before you use a NuGet tool to restore or push packages to an authenticated package source such as Azure Artifacts. This task installs the Azure Artifacts Credential Provider into the NuGet plugins directory if it is not already installed.

If your agent is behind a web proxy, the NuGetAuthenticate  will not set up nuget.exe, dotnet, and MSBuild to use the proxy. Then set the environment variable `http_proxy` and optionally `no_proxy` to your proxy settings as shown below.

```
nuget.exe config -set http_proxy=http://my.proxy.address:port
nuget.exe config -set http_proxy.user=mydomain\myUserName
```

Check this [NuGet CLI environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/cli-reference/cli-ref-environment-variables) variables for more information.